# Undefined local variable or method `make' when installing therubyracer on MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been developing on this project for about a year now, but about a month ago I ran into an issue where I had a gem installed that was incompatible with my version of ruby (using rbenv; 2.3.1). I blew up the directory, uninstalled all of my gems, uninstalled rbenv, then installed rbenv and ruby. My fellow developers haven't had any problem getting the project setup, but when I run `bundle install`, my install always seems to fail on `therubyracer 0.12.3` with the following error:

```
Fetching therubyracer 0.12.3
Installing therubyracer 0.12.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  current directory: /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer- 
0.12.3/ext/v8
/Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20191211-2125-b9wazv.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.3.0- 
static/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-
0.12.3/ext/v8
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top 
(required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

current directory: /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-
0.12.3/ext/v8
make "DESTDIR="
/Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top 
(required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in 
/Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-
18/2.3.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  therubyracer
```

I can't seem to find this same error reproduced anywhere. Prior to the install, when I run `which make` I get:

```
developer.rhapsody.com git:(master) which make
  /usr/bin/make
developer.rhapsody.com git:(master) make --version
  GNU Make 3.81
  Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
  PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

However, after I try to run `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'`, when I run `which make` I get

```
developer.rhapsody.com git:(master) which make
  /Users/deaster/.rbenv/shims/make
developer.rhapsody.com git:(master) make --version
  /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top 
  (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
      from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `load'
      from /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/make:23:in `<main>'
```

I've blown up this project and rbenv several times in order to get this working but I can't get past this step. My team members never run into this error so they're having a hard time helping me get setup. I understand that something is wrong with the make gem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is in the ` /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-
18/2.3.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out` file?

Answer (score 1):

The make gem has nothing to do with the GNU make program.

> A gem that shortcuts typing out forms and tables for SQL users.
> Assuming your model is named ModelName, just type
> Make.form.model("ModelName").now! in your controller and it will
> return an html-safe form based on your column names for creating a new
> record in your view. In addition, you can type
> Make.table.model("ModelName").now! to automatically generate a table.
>
> - https://rubygems.org/gems/make

It's just a really badly named gem of questionable quality.

Whats going on here is that you ran `gem install make` (or it was included in the Gemfile) and now the shim generated by RBenv is shadowing GNU make on your system. What I don't understand is how the gems authors could be so clueless and not see that this would be a HUGE problem.

Running `$ gem uninstall make` should fix the problem. Also ensure that its not in your Gemfile.

Comment: Wow, this whole time I thought they were the same make.

I was able to remove the make gem with `gem uninstall make`. I actually did find it in my Gemfile--must've been added by a team member recently--and after removing and running `bundle install`, I still get a similar error but slightly different. Instead of listing the repo where make should be, I get this:
```current directory: /Users/deaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
make "DESTDIR=" clean
rbenv: make: command not found```

Comment: Ah could be that you still have the rbenv shim in place. ‘rm /Users/deaster/.rbenv/shims/make’ should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I was able to get this working.

Unfortunately I'm not sure what fixed the issue. I didn't make any more changes to the project or environment between getting the `bundle install` errors and then finally being successful. The only thing that happened was my VSCode ran into some unrelated issue and crashed my computer. When I booted back up, `bundle install` was successful and I was able to run the project. I'm not sure what that's indicative of, but I'm still looking for more insight in case I run into this in the future.